# node.js : how to pass parameter from ejs to a global function?

Tags: function, parameters, global, ejs

my goal is to execute a function with a parameter which I take from a textbox in HTML file. I couldn't do it.

APP.JS

```
app.locals.printtest =  function (myparam) {

      console.log(myparam);

};
```

TEST.EJS

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
<%printtest(document.getElementById("name").value)%>
```

Comment: I also tried <%= and <%-. didn't work..

Comment: may DOM scripting be useful??

Comment: JQUERY .......?

Comment: or any other libraries?